# Can SDS drill bits be used with keyed single sleeve drills?

Tags: drill

Can SDS drill bits be used with keyed single sleeve drills? If yes, are there any precautions I have to take for ensuring the best result?

Comment: Never tried direct as I have a hex to SDS adapter for use in the chuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results will vary by the chuck configuration of your drill. You might get lucky; you might not.

If you chuck the bit in and it's wobbly, try shifting it a tiny amount -- it may work better. Be prepared to tighten the chuck frequently.

If you're drilling a lot of masonry, you might find an upgrade to a real rotary hammer drill (such as a Bosch bulldog) would improve your life a lot.

Comment: Does a rotary hammer drill always use SDS bits?

Comment: Almost yes. There are 2 sizes of sds (plus, or max), and also spline drives. Normal bits and roto hammers don't mix.